# Firestore subscribed document change type

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Whenever I subscribe to a collection of documents, I'm able to extract the changes to the documents, given that the listener returns DocumentChange. This way I can understand whether a given doc was created, modified or deleted.

How to get the DocumentChange when subscribing to a single document in the collection? The issue appears to be that this time the listener returns DocumentSnapshot instead of DocumentChange.

Comment: To understand better, do you need to know for example, when the value of a field inside a document has changed? If not, what exactly would you like to know when it comes to a single document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [DocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.documentsnapshot) contains everything you need to know about that one document.  Either it [exists()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.documentsnapshot.md#documentsnapshotexists) with data, or it does not.  You can check this state with each new snapshot for that one document, and react to that any way you like.  Since you are not performing a query with variable set of results, there is no need for more information.

Comment: Say a document is about to be deleted. If I'm subscribed to it using a query, the DocumentChange<DocumentData> allows me to get the documentData of the just deleted document using documentChange.doc. However, if I'm subscribed to it with a single document subscription, the DocumentSnapshot only gives me the ID of the deleted document. How do I extract the data of the deleted document from DocumentSnapshot?

Comment: You have to remember the prior snapshot to see what was in it. The API won't help you with that.